# Find word(s) between two values in a string

Tags: c#, .net, string, substring, indexof

I have a txt file as a string, and I need to find words between two characters and `Ltrim`/`Rtrim` everything else. It may have to be conditional because the two characters may change depending on the string.

Example:

```
car= (data between here I want) ;
car =  (data between here I want) </value>
```

Code:

```
int pos = st.LastIndexOf("car=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

if (pos >= 0)
{
     server = st.Substring(0, pos);..............
}
```

Comment: You want everything between 2 delimeters, but the delimeters can change? What happens if 2 different types of delimeters appear?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a simple extension method I use:

```
public static string Between(this string src, string findfrom, string findto)
{
    int start = src.IndexOf(findfrom);
    int to = src.IndexOf(findto, start + findfrom.Length);
    if (start < 0 || to < 0) return "";
    string s = src.Substring(
                   start + findfrom.Length, 
                   to - start - findfrom.Length);
    return s;
}
```

With this you can use

```
string valueToFind = sourceString.Between("car=", "</value>")
```

---

You can also try this:

```
public static string Between(this string src, string findfrom, 
                             params string[] findto)
{
    int start = src.IndexOf(findfrom);
    if (start < 0) return "";
    foreach (string sto in findto)
    {
        int to = src.IndexOf(sto, start + findfrom.Length);
        if (to >= 0) return
            src.Substring(
                       start + findfrom.Length,
                       to - start - findfrom.Length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

With this you can give multiple ending tokens (their order is important)

```
string valueToFind = sourceString.Between("car=", ";", "</value>")
```

Answer (score 15):

You could use regex

```
var input = "car= (data between here I want) ;";
var pattern = @"car=\s*(.*?)\s*;"; // where car= is the first delimiter and ; is the second one
var result = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Groups[1].Value;
```