# Get Specific Text in Text

Tags: vb.net, text

```
text1/text2/text3
```

In this text, I am trying to get text3 only. Is there anyway that I can do this in VB.Net?

By the way, "text1/text2/" is fixed. So they are not changing.

Comment: `String.Split("/")(2)`

Answer (score 1):

use substring since you know the index position of the character.The code below is usefull for you if the "text1 and text2" varies dynamically

```
    Dim line as string="text1/text2/text3"
    Dim _split = line.Split("/")(2)
    MessageBox.Show(_split)
```

Comment: It would probably be best to verify that there are at least three elements in the array returned by the `Split` method before attempting to use the third element

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with removing first 22 character.

Example

```
X = text1/text2/text3
Y = X.text.Remove(0, 12)
Result = text3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String.Substring(Int32, Int32) method.
String.Substring(12, totalLength - 12) will return the "text3" in your case. Here totalLength is the total length of the text "text1/text2/text3".

Check this link from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) website:

Answer (score -1):

you can use SubString like

```
string sub = "text1/text2/text3".Substring(12, 5);
```

VB

```
Dim subString As String = "text1/text2/text3".Substring(12, 5)
```

or you can refer to this [Find text in string with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709821/find-text-in-string-with-c-sharp)

Comment: the OP specified VB.  `sub` is a reserved word in VB.  Also, the result of your code would be the first 12 characters, not what the OP asked for.