# How to find the position of a word inside a string in c# or python?

Tags: c#, python, string

what would be the easiest way to find the position of a word inside a string?

for example:

`the cat sat on the mat`

`the word "cat" appears in the second position`

or

`the word "on" appears in the fourth position`

any help would be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find text in string with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709821/find-text-in-string-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.index` in Python, it will return the position of the first occurrence.

```
test = 'the cat sat on the mat'
test.index('cat')  # returns 4
```

EDIT: re-reading your question, you'll want the position of the word. To do this, you should convert your sentence into a list:

```
test = 'the cat sat on the mat'
words = test.split(' ')
words.index('cat')  # returns 1, add 1 to get the actual position.
```

Answer (score 0):

in python you can use find function:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :

```
s = 'the cat sat on the mat'
worlist = s.split(' ')
pos=1
for word in worlist:
   if word == 'cat':
     print pos
     break
   else:
     pos = pos + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

C# way:

```
string wordToFind = "sat";
string text = "the cat sat on the mat";
int index = text.Split(' ').ToList().FindIndex((string str) => { return str.Equals(wordToFind, StringComparison.Ordinal); }) + 1;
```