# .Net regex for string between \" "\

Tags: c#, regex, substring

I have been trying to get the `id` from the following text

```
<body id=\"body\" runat=\"server\">
```

In C# using substring or even Regex, but nothing seems to be working. No matter what regex i use, i always get the whole line back. I have been trying to use `^id`, `^id.*`, `^id=\\\\\\\\.*` and `id=.*` but they don't either work or give me the desired output. Is there any way i can get the id portion from this text which is enclosed between the characters `\" "\`?

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Ban hammer a bit much... but [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1324033)

Comment: As noted in the regex tag - "NOTE: Asking for HTML, JSON, etc. regexes tends to be met with negative reactions. If there is a parser for it, use that instead."

Comment: is it not possible even if you convert HTML into a simple text and make it look like a string like " body id=\"body\" runat=\"server\" "? and then try to use regex over this string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709821/find-text-in-string-with-c-sharp

Comment: There is not string between \" and "\!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        string htmlString = "<body id=\"body\" runat=\"server\">";

        Regex regex = new Regex("id=\"(.*?)\"");
        Match m = regex.Match(htmlString);
        Group g = m.Groups[1];
        string id = g.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(id); //body
```

Test here:
http://rextester.com/BQSF93427