# Check if Id is in array of strings in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am working on a crystal report. Now I added a new parameter for CustomerId so that the report result can be filtered according to that.

In the interface we can select multiple customers, so the values will be something like

```
strCustomerid = '1,2'; // 1 & 2 are customer ids
```

If I select only one customer the filtering works perfect, but when I select multiple its not.

I tried something like below code in Crystal Report record selection formula

```
{ihCustomerId} IN {?strCustomerid}
```

Then I get the error `an integer is required here`, so i had to convert it into integer, I think thats where the mistake happen.

```
{ihCustomerId} IN ToNumber ({?strCustomerid})
```

Now if I select one customer it works perfectly, but on multiple its showing no result.

What is wrong here? how can I correct this? please help.

Comment: You can do postback on combobox etc and filter the dataview

Answer (score 0):

What about the solutions here, I'm pretty sure they can help you

[Find text in string with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709821/find-text-in-string-with-c-sharp)

cheers,
es

Answer (score 0):

Your incoming {?strCustomerid} appears to be a string, with values separated by a comma.
The field in the data you are trying to select from appears to be a number {ihCustomerId}, so you'll have to first separate each element of {?strCustomerid} then convert {ihCustomerId} to a string to then do the comparison.  This should work for you (in Crysta Syntax):

```
CStr({ihCustomerId},0,"") IN Split({?strCustomerid},",")
```

CStr converts to a string, and the parameters ensure the number is formatted correctly. Split will split the incoming parameter into distinct elements within an array, using a comma as the character to split upon.