# How can I improve this Console Application?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, console, console-application

I am trying to highlight an specific word from a file and show all the text in the console with the highlighted word.

I have tried to optimize it with Regular Expressions but got stuck when trying to color red just the desired match in each sentence it appears. So I ended using the For Loop alternative instead.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt");



        string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        var word = text.Split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            if (word[i].Contains("World", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write(word[i] + " ");
                Console.ResetColor();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(word[i] + " ");
            }

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find text in string with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709821/find-text-in-string-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Console.Write() is an expensive operation. if you need performance improvement one option is to use it as less as possible. Build the string text using a StringBuilder(avoid using Concatenation or string interpolation in this case ) till you find the expected word(word need to be highlighted), once you find the word which needs to be highlighted, just Console it. Avoid Console.Write() in each iteration

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposition using Regex :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt");

        String searched = "World";
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"\b\w*" + searched + @"\w*\b");

        string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        int lastIndex = 0;

        MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(text);

        foreach(Match m in matches)
        {
            Console.Write(text.Substring(lastIndex, m.Index - lastIndex));
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.Write(m.Value);
            Console.ResetColor();

            lastIndex = m.Index + m.Length;
        }

        if(lastIndex < text.Length)
            Console.Write(text.Substring(lastIndex, text.Length - lastIndex));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

However, I'm afraid about performance about Substring repetition...