# how to search a word in a sentence text [C#]

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I don't have idea How can I search word for a sentence in C#. 
In case the word is anywhere in the sentence.

My plan is if have the word that I set up in anywhere the sentence the button1 will visible.

e.g. => I set up the word is 'ABC' in label1.

if the sentence in textbox1 is : `I'am ABC.`
                or : `ABC is here.`
                or : `The ABC is come.`
                or : `12345ABCDEFG`

The Button1 will visible.

I tried coding :

```
string textToSearchFor = "ABC";
int index = textbox1.Text.IndexOf(textToSearchFor, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
if (index >= 0)
{
    button1.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    button1.Visible = false;
}
```

but It didn’t go as planned.

-Edited-

Because When in textbox1 value is `ABC` then button1.Visible is true

But when textbox1 value is `ABC is here.` or `The ABC is come.` then button1.Visible is false

Please anyone help me how? Thank you.

Comment: What didn't go to plan? The string check looks like it should work as you intended.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709821/find-text-in-string-with-c-sharp

Comment: You "tried coding", but *where* did you put the code? Are you sure it is getting called when you expect it to? Can you put a breakpoint in the code and see if you hit it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's unclear what "didn't go as planned" really means but you have a much cleaner option available to you.  We're going to use the `Contains` extension method.

```
button1.Visible = textbox1.Text.Contains("ABC");
```

You haven't really specified where you're trying to run this code from but if it's on a timer's event, or something similar, this will effectively bind the button's visibility to the boolean result of the `Contains` method.

Do note: this isn't case insensitive; I'd call that a different topic ... probably.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's very easy <3  and I edited my question what "didn't go as planned" I think everybody will understand me.