# Retrieving string from a string which is in between two String?

Tags: c#, string, design-patterns

i have a string Like

```
"Hello i want to go."
```

my code give `"want to go."` 
but i need string between `" i "` and `" to "` how can i get this? my code is as below.

```
string[] words = Regex.Split("Hello i want to go.", " i ");
string respons = words[1];
```

Comment: Are you interested in retrieving it using Regular Expressions or as an array index?

Comment: using regular Expresson.

Comment: This isn't enough information - is your code supposed to find the word "want" or is it supposed to remove the words "hello," "i," "to," and "go"? Or is it supposed to retrieve the third word from a string? Or the middle word from a string? As it stands, the problem you've described can be solved simply by doing 'respons = "want"'.

Comment: i find solution in [This link][1] . .


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082103/find-words-between-two-values-in-a-string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it's work

```
public static string Between(this string src, string findfrom, string findto)
{
    int start = src.IndexOf(findfrom);
    int to = src.IndexOf(findto, start + findfrom.Length);
    if (start < 0 || to < 0) return "";
    string s = src.Substring(
                   start + findfrom.Length, 
                   to - start - findfrom.Length);
    return s;
}
```

and it can be called as

```
string respons = Between("Hello i want to go."," i "," to ");
```

it return `want`

Answer (score 3):

```
string input = "Hello i want to go.";
Regex regex = new Regex(@".*\s[Ii]{1}\s(\w*)\sto\s.*");
Match match = regex.Match(input);
string result = string.Empty;
if (match.Success)
{
    result = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

This regex will match any 'word' between 'i' (not case sensitive) and 'to'.

EDIT: changed ...to.* => to\s.* as suggested in the comments.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `{1}` is not needed, and shouldn't `to.*` be `to\s.*`? Otherwise a good answer.

Comment: Actually this is what he wanted ... my solution at the bottom is wrong since it assumed he was looking for the index of "want".

Comment: Regex(@".*\s[Ii]{1}\s(\w*)\sto\s.*"); how it works? but i am sure my solution is in this code

Comment: The regex caputers any word character (letter, number, underscore), (\w*), between I/i, [Ii]{1}, and to (the \s is a whitespace match and .* is anything before and after)

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "Hello I want to go.";
string result = input.Split(" ")[2];
```

If you want the word after the "i" then:

```
string result = input.Split(" i ")[1].Split(" ")[0];
```

Comment: if there is string like "Hello manoj i want to go." then ?actually i want text between i and to.

Comment: @manoj try this: `string result = "want";` guaranteed to work.

Comment: @manoj At no point in the question did you say that that's what you want.

Comment: Nice, @Botz3000.  Sometimes we just need to take a step back and look for the simple answer. :)

Comment: -1This answer as well will not work in regards to using the Split() method come on guys the Split(" ") should be Split(' ') replace the double quotes

Comment: is Split() method accept String ? and :) i just not need "Want" i need String Between " i " and " to ".

Comment: @DJKRAZE: I'm not a terribly competent c# guy.  VB is my forte. Feel free to edit my answer for the correct c# syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string input = "Hello I want to go.";
    string[] sentenceArray = input.Split(' ');
    string required = sentenceArray[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
string s = "Hello i want to go.";
string[] words = s.split(' ');
string response = wor
```

Answer (score 0):

just do it with one simple line of code

```
 var word = "Hello i want to go.".Split(' ')[2];
```

//Returns the word "want"

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using Regex which gives you the index of each occurrence of "want":

```
string str = "Hello i want to go. Hello i want to go. Hello i want to go.";
Match match = Regex.Match(str, "want");

while(match.Success){
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Index: {0}", match.Index));
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere does it say Regex...

```
string result = input.Split.Skip(2).Take(1).First()
```